# How to read Binary Files using command line argument and print it out in C?

Tags: c, binaryfiles

So Ive got a struct of

```
struct records {
    short link; 
    double gate; 
    unsigned char bar;
    int rest; 
    char rink; 
};
```

And now I want to read binary inputs and print them out using `fread()`. I'm just having trouble figuring out what exactly to do.

So I've only got

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
}
```

So first off, how do you open a binary file? All the examples I've seen online only use `main()` and when using `fopen()` they always specify the input. How to use the command line arguments to specify which file to open?

And then, how do I read those files into the `struct` I've created and print them out?

Any help appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: Hint 1: You forgot the ``return 0;`` statement to return the result of ``main()``. Hint 2: Once you made the changes of hint 1, set a breakpoint at the return statement and inspect the contents of argc and argv while supplying different command line arguments to the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the name of the binary file as argument when you run the program.

`argv[0]` will be the name of the program itself and the name of the file in `argv[1]`.

As [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) mentioned in the comment, you must ensure that `argv[1]` actually exists before you access it or it will cause error.

Something like

```
if(argc<2)
{
    printf("\nError");
    return -1;
}
```

should take care of that.

Then do

```
FILE *fin=fopen(argv[1], "rb");
```

and then use `fread()` to read from the file.

The second argument of `fopen()` is the *mode* in which file is opened.
r and b in "rb" means read and binary respectively.

As for `fread()`, first create a variable, say `a` of type `struct records`.

Then use

```
fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, fin);
```

Here we pass address of `a` so that the read data will be stored there.
`sizeof(a)` says the size of each block read by `fread()` and the `1` is the number of blocks that should be read.

`fread()` will return the number of blocks that were read successfully which in our case is `1`.
If the number of blocks that we asked to be read and the number of blocks that were actually read are not same, either the file ended or some error occurred.

Afterwards we can access each element of `a`.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html

Comment: Thanks so much. Ive done the error handling, like the `argc<2` and more like `if(fin==null)`. Could you please elaborate more on `fread()`?

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe I added some more content. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again. I have a couple questions. First, does the `1` in the `fread` refer to how many it reads from the `struct`, or just how many `structs`. So for my `struct`, would it still be `1` or `5`? Second, to access each element of `a` and print it, would I just do `printf("%d", a[0])` and so on for `a[1]`? Lastly, we've been told to "Read each field separately with its own `fread` call." Does this differ from what you have said?

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe The `1` refers to the number of blocks which in this case is a single `struct records`. A single block will have all the 5 members. So it's `1` and _not_ `5`. To access each element of `a`, you will have to go for the manual way ie, `printf("%d,%lf,...", a.link, a.gate, ...)`. _Reading each field separately with its own `fread()`_ and what I suggested are unlikely to be the same. And I don't even know if it can be done.

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe I guess by each field you mean the `link`, `gate`, etc

Comment: Yeah, thats what I assumed it to mean. Also I tried `fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, fin)` after creating `struct records a` and doing `printf("%d,%lf,...` and it didnt work. It told me `fread must read each struct field separately`. So im thinking each field refers to each thing in the struct, `link`, `gate`...

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe Does the input file have the data in the correct format? How did you make it?

Comment: Yeah im sure its in the correct format. I didnt make it, the professor did. I have no control over the input file. It is a `bin` file

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe Then I'm afraid I don't know.